how to apply changes i did on my hard disk folders in android studio?
i created a new folder on my hard disk in my project name drawable-v24 and copied a file to the folder. but in android studio i don't have that folder only the drawable folder. i tried to file > sync project with gradle files but it didn't change anything then i did file > invalidate caches... and it did restart but also it didn't show the new folder. i'm using android studio ladybug 2024.2.1 patch 1.
in the attached image on the left the android studio folders. on the right my hard disk folders.


The tree view in Android Studio does not show folders, what it displays could be described as categories. The drawable category e.g. will contain all files from folders drawable* folders.
